# Can enum cases contain a list of classes?

Tags: swift, enums, subclass

Can an enum contain a list of classes?

I have a superclass Activity: SKScene { }, which has sub-private class Activity01: Activity { }, sub-private class Activity02: Activity { } and a sub-private class Activity03: Activity { }.
Each sub-private class contains a timed activity. When the timer runs out before the user solves the activity, a GameOver scene (class GameOver: Activity { }) pops up (with text “Bad luck try again”).

I am trying to create an enum in the GameOver class to be triggered in touches began to return the user to their last activity but I cannot solve this one. When tapped it always returns to Activity01.

Here is my attempt:

```
 …}  // Activity03 sub-private class closure


    class GameOver: Activity {

        enum classes {
            case Activity01
            case Activity02
            case Activity03
                  }

        var firstClass = classes.Activity01
        var secondClass = classes.Activity02
        var thirdClass = classes.Activity03

        let restartGameText = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "AvenirNext-HeavyItalic")

        init(size: CGSize, won:Bool) {
            super.init(size: size)

            startGameText.removeFromParent()

            restartGameText.text = "Bad luck try again"
            restartGameText.horizontalAlignmentMode = SKLabelHorizontalAlignmentMode.center
            restartGameText.verticalAlignmentMode = SKLabelVerticalAlignmentMode.center
            restartGameText.fontSize = 60
            restartGameText.fontColor = SKColor(red: 230/255, green: 60/255, blue: 70/255, alpha: 1)
            restartGameText.position = CGPoint(x: scene!.size.width/2.0, y: scene!.size.height/2.0)
            restartGameText.zPosition = 5
            addChild(restartGameText)

            let pulseAction = SKAction.sequence([SKAction.fadeAlpha(to: 1, duration: 1), SKAction.fadeAlpha(to: 0.7, duration: 1)])
            restartGameText.run(SKAction.repeatForever(pulseAction))

        }

        required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
            fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
        }


        override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

            if firstClass == classes.Activity01 {

                let transition = SKTransition.fade(withDuration: 2.0)
                let activity01 = Activity01(size: size)
                view?.presentScene(activity01, transition: transition)

            } else if secondClass == classes.Activity02 {

                let transition = SKTransition.fade(withDuration: 2.0)
                let activity02 = Activity02(size: size)
                view?.presentScene(activity02, transition: transition)

            } else if thirdClass == classes.Activity03 {

                let transition = SKTransition.fade(withDuration: 2.0)
                let activity03 = Activity03(size: size)
                view?.presentScene(activity03, transition: transition)

            }
        }
    }   //GameOver class closure
}  // Activity Superclass closure
```

Is there a way to return to Activity02 or Activity03 if they were the last activity?

Answer (score 1):

The below enum declaration is perfectly fine. But it is not having enum type as Classes here. It is just an enum without any type, which is allowed in Swift.

```
   enum classes {
        case Activity01
        case Activity02
        case Activity03
   }
```

Just for your reference about [Enum](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Enumerations.html) from "The Swift Programming Language" from Apple:

> Swift enumeration cases don’t have an integer value set by default,
>   unlike languages like C and Objective-C.....Instead, the different
>   enumeration cases are values in their own right.

And the reason for always getting `Activity01` is, you have assigned `firstClass` as `Activity01` ans so on, in your code.

```
var firstClass = classes.Activity01
var secondClass = classes.Activity02
var thirdClass = classes.Activity03
```

So, when `firstClass` is compared with `classes.Activity01` in `touchesBegan` method, it will always match. That's the reason, you are getting "`Activity01`" always.

You should have instance member to track the `lastClass` of `enum classes` type and it should be compared with `classes.Activity01 / 02 / 03` in `touchesBegan` method, instead of comparing it with `firstClass` with `classes.Activity01` and so on. It should be something like this.

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    if lastClass == classes.Activity01 {

        let transition = SKTransition.fade(withDuration: 2.0)
        let activity01 = Activity01(size: size)
        view?.presentScene(activity01, transition: transition)

    } else if lastClass == classes.Activity02 {

        let transition = SKTransition.fade(withDuration: 2.0)
        let activity02 = Activity02(size: size)
        view?.presentScene(activity02, transition: transition)

    } else if lastClass == classes.Activity03 {

        let transition = SKTransition.fade(withDuration: 2.0)
        let activity03 = Activity03(size: size)
        view?.presentScene(activity03, transition: transition)

    }
}
```

By this, last activity class can be correctly displayed even it is Activity 02 / 03.

Comment: I can't make this work. I am not sure if the cases (Activity01, etc) in the enum is actually referencing the sub classes (Activity01, etc). How do I write the lastClass instance member to track the enum classes type corresponding to the actual sub classes?